# How to use the word “duplicate”

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I would like to warn my customers that names can be duplicate. How do I put it in words?

In MS Word when I entered `Name can be duplicate.`, it draws a green line under `duplicate`. What's my mistake?

Suppose I have two products in my store with same name. I don’t want my customers to be confused when they see two different products with the same name. If I have to warn them with a written notice, how should I write that?

For now, I wrote it as “Multiple products with same name can exist at a time.” But I don’t understand why my initial statement was wrong.

Comment: What do you mean, names can be duplicate?

Comment: Two people can have the same name? 'Please give both your given name and family name'? what are you getting at?

Comment: Your mistake comes from using Microsoft instead of `vi`, obviously. I promise that if you upgrade, the green line will go away.

Comment: I think you are looking for "names are not *unique*". I think. Why MS Word puts a green line there, I can't possibly know. Perhaps it considers *duplicate* without an article an adjective, awaiting a noun to follow.

Comment: Updated the question. If its not name, it can be something else that can be duplicate. How would I form a statement with placeholder for that duplicate thing.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA It might be looking for "names can be duplicate", "names can be duplicates" or "names can be duplicated". "Name can be duplicate" doesn't sound right

Comment: @tchrist You're just asking for a `vi` vs `emacs` rivalry here ... :)

Comment: "Names can be duplicated" sounds like the customer can *copy* someone else's name, rather than what you're trying to say - that it may be the same as someone else's, by chance.

Comment: Seems to me that what you were originally trying to state was that "names can be duplicates" (of each other). That way, it's clear that you mean to use the word as a noun (see @fluffy's answer). As it stands, your question is a little confusing. However, I didn't edit your post because I'm not entirely sure that that is in fact what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Duplicate" can be a noun or a verb.  So, for example, both "Name can be a duplicate," or "names can be duplicated," make sense.

Comment: `Name can be a duplicate` seems right to Word.

Answer (score 3):

You either mean to say, "Names can be duplicated" or "Duplicate names are a possibility" or "(Any of the) names may be a duplicate".  Better still, as RegDwight said, "Names may not be unique."

Answer (score 0):

Clearly Microsoft Word does not know that *duplicate* is an adjective (as well as a verb and a noun). The *OED* says:

> **duplicate**, *adj.*  1. Double, twofold, consisting of two corresponding parts; that is made or exists in two corresponding examples.  2. Double, doubled; consisting of twice the number or quantity.  3. That is the exact counterpart or ‘double’ of something already in existence.